# How to pass double value from view into controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

Entity:

```
public class Material
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public int? Unit { get; set; }
    public double? Count { get; set; }
    public double? Amount { get; set; }
    public double? Cost { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Edit(int id, Material material)
{
    ...

}
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Count" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Count" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Count" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

If I try to pass `10.2`
[image]
[image]

If I try to pass `10,2`
[image]

On the internet I came across the following

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <globalization
       enableClientBasedCulture="true"        
       culture="en-GB"/>
</system.web>
```

It need to past into Web.config, but i don't have this file in my solution

ASP.NET Core MVC (.NET 6)

Comment: Do you have any config files for your project?  Try adding change to your existing config file.

Comment: @ДимаМихайлечко: If you are using the IIS then you can add the web.config to your project manually.

Comment: @Jackdaw I added web.config file and nothing changed, web.config needs to be registered in Program.cs ?

Comment: @ДимаМихайлечко: No, the `web.config` not required to be registered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to enable request localization on the app side:

```cs
var app = builder.Build();
var supportedCultures = new[] { "en-GB" };
var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions().SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
    .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
    .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);

app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
```

Or you can just manually manipulate the default culture on app start:

```cs
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

Read more - [Implement a strategy to select the language/culture for each request in a localized ASP.NET Core app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization/select-language-culture?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configure-localization-middleware).